# refactor params permited to change input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gsub

at first I'm newbie in rails , I have rails application witch contains profile for each user , in profile based on each user gender front send a params with . for example "Mr . " but in my controller i could not accecpt so it return error

> "#<ArgumentError: 'mr.' is not a valid title>",

i want to edit my controller to get params and change it to without dot ,I think maybe it could possible to use gsub but when i try to edit it returns error

> "exception": "#<NoMethodError: undefined method `gsub' for #<Enumerator: "mr.":gsub(" ")>>",

,is it possible to refactor in params permit. it's my controller

```
def update
    if (profile_update_params.present?)
      profile_update_result = ::Api::V1::Profile::Update.call(profile_params: profile_update_params, profile: @current_user.profile, request: request)
      return render json: Helpers::ErrorsHandler.view_parse(profile_update_result), status: :bad_request if profile_update_result.errors
    end

    if (user_update_params.present?)
      user_update_result = ::Api::V1::User::Update.call(user_params: user_update_params, user: @current_user)
      return render json: Helpers::ErrorsHandler.view_parse(user_update_result), status: :bad_request if user_update_result.errors
    end

    result = sheriff
    render result.view
  end
```

and this is my params permit

```
  def profile_update_params
    params.permit(:phone, :title, :email, :gender, :first_name, :last_name, :description, :job_title, :time_zone)
  
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found using gusb is currect but i'm using in wrong place ,I do not need to change hole params to string so I took my field out of params and change my params permit as bellow and every things is going fine

```
 def profile_update_params
params.permit(:phone, :email, :gender, :first_name, :last_name, :description, :job_title, :time_zone).merge({title: params[:title].to_s.gsub(".", "")})
end
```